# Multi joins in context of BelongsTo

Tags: laravel-nova

In the context of Laravel Nova. I have the following tables in a database:

order:

- id
- group_id (references group.id)

group:

- id
- user_id (references user.id)

user:

- id
- member_id (integer)

In my index view of order I can easily display a column with user_id using this in my Order Resource:

BelongsTo::make('User ID','Group', 'App\Nova\Group')->display('user_id'),

But how do I display member_id? Pseudo wise:

BelongsTo::make('User ID','Group', 'App\Nova\Group')->display('user_id') --> BelongsTo::make('Member ID','User', 'App\Nova\User')->display('member_id') ?

Any help appreciated - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Write a specific method in the model and use it:

```
/**
 * Get the user that owns the phone.
 */
public function userId()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');
}
```

And in the resource field, specify this method:

```
BelongsTo::make('Member ID','userId', 'App\User')
```